# cannot get phing to run at all

Tags: php, phing

Max OS X 10.7.. when i run `phing -v` i get the following errors:

```
Warning: require_once(phing/Project.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/lib/php/pear/phing/Phing.php on line 22

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'phing/Project.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/lib/php/pear/phing/Phing.php on line 22
```

#### Here are the commands i used:

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install phing/phing
```

#### Here is my php.ini:

```
include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php"
```

#### running whereis for php, pear, and phing returns:

```
bash-3.2$ whereis php
/usr/bin/php

bash-3.2$ whereis pear
/usr/bin/pear

bash-3.2$ whereis phing
/usr/bin/phing
```

#### running config-get for pear returns:

```
→ pear config-get php_dir
/usr/lib/php/pear
```

checking this folder, `system.php` and `phing.php` both exist in this path.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Seems like `include_path` is somehow broken.

#### Check PEAR's directory:

```
pear config-get php_dir
/usr/lib/php
```

Whatever directory is returned, it should contain PEAR files (`System.php` and `phing` files in particular)

#### Check that correct `php.ini` is used:

Run `php --ini` and see what INI file is being loaded. Then make sure this INI files contains PEAR directory in it's `include_path`

#### Check `include_path`:

Run `php -c /path/to/php.ini -r 'echo get_include_path() . "\n";'`.

---

**Update**

The problem is indeed with `include_path` since the error message reports `(include_path='.:')` which clearly shows that PEAR is NOT in your include path. This means that wrong `php.ini` is being loaded for CLI PHP. To fix it, find correct `php.ini` file (step 2) and add

```
include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php/pear"
```

to it.

Comment: i have updated my question with a few responses to your answere here.. in particular pear directory, php.ini.. I have also uninstalled mamp completely along with phing, and phpdocumentor.

Comment: I ended up having to run `pear config-set php_dir /usr/lib/php` and then restarting MAMP, uncommenting `/private/etc/php.ini -> include_path line`

Answer (score 1):

I solve it simple ...

i'm configuring my /etc/paths to include propel generator on my path ambient.

then i add /Application/XAMPP/bin and /Application/XAMPP/Propel/generator/bin

i was getting that include error. Mac system comes with php preinstalled ... so, propel generator was getting wrong php installation.

I solve it simple ... i just changed the order of /etc/paths folders ...

as you see my /etc/paths file:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/Applications/XAMPP/Propel/generator/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Want to add one more easier solution for mac LION users (those who install stuff via macport ) , might work for leopard too

1. download this script anywhere, doesn't matter where it is

   ```
   curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > go-pear.phar
   ```
2. run this command

   ```
   sudo php -q go-pear.phar
   ```
3. it will ask you the paths, you shouldn't need to change it, but just check these paths contains any pear related files.
4. it will ask you if you want to update php.ini for you with these includes path [Y]

you are done! type phing and you should ask for your build.xml

Answer (score -2):

Or if you don't have access to the server, you can do this:

`$root = $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

It'll always reference the root of your project, and you can then reference the folder/file from that. 
You don't have to touch the server if done that way.