# No INI files are loaded (php.ini)

Tags: php, apache, pear, propel, ini

When I was trying to install propel and tried to run it with this command:

> library/propel/generator/bin/propel-gen

I always get this error:

> Warning: require_once(phing/Phing.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GentseFeesten/library/propel/generator/bin/phing.php on line 39
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'phing/Phing.php'
>   (include_path='.:') in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GentseFeesten/library/propel/generator/bin/phing.php
>   on line 39

When I searched for a solution I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253187/cannot-get-phing-to-run-at-all) topic on stackoverflow.

At the following step :

> Check that correct php.ini is used:
>
> Run php --ini and see what INI file is being loaded. Then make sure
>   this INI files contains PEAR directory in it's include_path

I got this from my command line:

[image]

No ini files are loaded ...

I am using MAMP with php version 5.4.4 .
When I check the php version with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` 
I see that the php version is "5.4.4". 
 And when I check the php version in terminal with

> php -v

I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
When I run

> locate php.ini

in terminal I get this result:
[image]

I've added `.:/usr/lib/php/pear` to the php.ini file in php5.4.4/ but still the same result ..

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691767/where-does-mamp-keep-its-php-ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the version to the version of my MAMP and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The command line version of PHP is a completely separate thing than the PHP in a webserver. Your command line version looks like it's an unconfigured CLI executable located "somewhere", and I think you should install a matching version of PHP 5.4.4 CLI on your machine. Then you'd be able to configure PEAR as well, and get a working copy of Phing.

Where is your current PHP on the command line? `which php`
What configuration does it have? `php -i`