# Phing execute error : Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, apache, config, pear, phing

I have a problem with phing.

I want to start `phing` in the commandline with " :> phing " but if I do this, I get this error:

> Warning: require_once(phing/Project.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in C:\develop\php\pear\pear\phing\Phing.php on
>   line 19
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'phing/Project.php'
>   (include_path='C:\develop\php\pear\pear/../classes;.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\develop\php\pear\pear\phing\Phing.php on line 19

I installed Apache and php. This worked.

I tested using

```
php -c "c:/develop/php/php.info" -r "echo get_include_path();"
```

and got

```
-> .;C:\php\pear
```

What can I do. I looked here but this not help me:

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253187/cannot-get-phing-to-run-at-all)**

Comment: it says `phing/Project.php` doesn't exists...

Comment: this exist but i think the problem is in the php.ini file.

Comment: are you using the `phar` archive?

Answer (score 1):

Your include path is not setup correctly.

Run `$ pear list-files phing/phing` and have a look at the first php file. It will have a path `C:\develop\php\pear\pear\phing\...`.

Edit your php.ini and append that path to the include path:

```
include_path=C:\develop\php\pear\pear;.;...
```